# How can apply a function to individual tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm trying to build additional tab functionality to a tab component I've built using W3 tabs. The required functionality is:

- A tab with > 3 `<li>` will have the remainder hidden and revealed when a button is clicked
- Output a count of all items in a tab and output in button
- Add multiple tab components to a page

The problem is that my function isn't specific and it falls over when the `> 3` condition of one of my if statements isn't met or if there are multiple tab components on the page.

I've also tried to make the code DRY (see the commented code) but again, I'm not sure how to construct the function so that it applies individually to each ul and also each tab component.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zh56sryg/1/)

```
function tabCount() { 
  var publication = $('.content .publications li');
  var project = $('.content .projects li');
  var publications = publication.length;
  var projects = project.length;


  if (publications > 3) {
    publication.slice(0,4).addClass('show');
    publications = publications - 3;
    $('.content .publications').next('.all').children('span').text(publications);
  } else { 
    publication.addClass('show');
    $('.all').hide();
  }

  if ( projects > 3) {
    console.log(projects)
    project.slice(0,4).addClass('show');
    projects = projects - 3;
    $('.content .projects').next('.all').children('span').text(projects);
  } else { 
    publication.addClass('show');
    $('.all').hide();
  }

  // var parent = $('.content ul')
  // var test = $('.content ul li');
  // var testLength = test.length;
  //
  // parent.each(function( ) {
  //   if (testLength > 3) {
  //     test.slice(0,4).addClass('show');
  //     testLength = testLength - 3;
  //     $('.content ul').next('.all').children('span').text(testLength);
  //   } else {
  //     $('.content ul li').addClass('show');
  //     $('.all').hide();
  //   }
  // });
}
tabCount();


  $('.all').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').addClass('show');
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through your uls then using `$(this)` & `.find()` get required elements i.e : **lis** then hide/show same .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function tabCount() {
  //loop through content > ul 
  $(".content ul").each(function() {
    //get length of li 
    var testLength = $(this).find("li").length
    if (testLength > 3) {
      $(this).find("li").slice(0, 3).addClass('show');
      testLength = testLength - 3;
      //hide li which doesn't have class show
      $(this).find("li:not('.show')").hide()
      //add total to button span
      $(this).closest(".content").find('.all').children('span').text(testLength);
    } else {
      $(this).find("li").addClass('show');
      $(this).closest(".content").find('.all').hide();
    }
  });
}
tabCount();


$('.all').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').show()
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 20em;
  font-family: "lucida grande", sans-serif;
}

[role="tablist"] {
  margin: 0 0 -0.1em;
  overflow: visible;
}

[role="tab"] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  background: hsl(220, 20%, 94%);
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before,
[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"] {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]:not(:focus):not(:hover)::before {
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(218, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0.3em;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  box-shadow: none;
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"]:hover,
[role="tab"]:focus,
[role="tab"]:active {
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tabpanel"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.7em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  border-radius: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em;
  content: '';
}

[role="tabpanel"] p {
  margin: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"] *+p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="nils-tab" id="nils">
      Nils Frahm
    </button>
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="agnes-tab" id="agnes" tabindex="-1">
      Agnes Obel
    </button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="nils-tab" aria-labelledby="nils" class="content">
    <ul class="publications">
      <li>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="agnes-tab" aria-labelledby="agnes" hidden="" class="content">
    <ul class="projects">
      <li>A gdfgdfg dfgdf gd.</li>
      <li>B 456465 656 periam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>C Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>D Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>E Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>F Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>G Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="nils-tab2" id="nils2">
      Nils Frahm 2
    </button>
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="agnes-tab2" id="agnes2" tabindex="-1">
      Agnes Obel 2
    </button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="nils-tab2" aria-labelledby="nils2" class="content">
    <ul class="publications">
      <li>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="agnes-tab2" aria-labelledby="agnes2" hidden="" class="content">
    <ul class="projects">
      <li>A gdfgdfg dfgdf gd.</li>
      <li>B 456465 656 periam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>C Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/js/tabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you. The only issue I can see is that once you click on a tab the second tab component is hidden. I think that this might be the w3 script adding a hidden attribute.